# Aligning the right grid size with summed height of dynamic grids on left

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am working through this code:

`demo.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
  paper2: {
    height: "100%",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function FullWidthGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
          <Paper className={classes.paper2}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>        
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Demo from './demo';

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

But I am getting the following formatting for the box layout:

[image]

(1) Is there a way to make the right grid not overlap with the boxes on the bottom row ?

(2) I need the box on the right to be of same height as the total number of grids on left which is dynamic in number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.paper2`:

```
paper2: {
  height: "100%",
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  boxSizing: 'border-box'
}
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit interesting-bush-6xidm]

Answer (score 1):

`.makeStyles-paper2-3 {` has a padding of `16px` along-with `height:100%` which is causing the right `div` to overflow. Remove the `padding` and it will not overflow.

However, if you want to provide the padding to your content inside, you can do so by using a child `div`

Try this:

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
    <Paper className={classes.paper2} style={{padding: '0'}} > {/*Removed padding from here*/}
        <div style={{padding: '16px'}}>xs=12 sm=6</div> {/* Added padding  here */}
    </Paper>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!!